# Change position pull element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got two inline-block elements side by side. If I'm changing the position of the second one (right -300px), the first one stays and not got pulled by the second one.

If you are clicking on `<div class="navigation"></div>` the `<nav class="main-nav">` got `right: -300px;` but the first element with the blue background does not move to the right side.

Have a look: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7jqmtcon/)

```
<section class="sidebar">
          <div class="navigation">
          </div><nav class="main-nav">
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Lorem</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Lorem</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Lorem</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Lorem</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Lorem</span></a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
      </section>
```

This my jQuery for toggle the class:

```
$( ".navigation" ).click(function() {
  $( ".main-nav" ).toggleClass( "open" );
});

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}

.sidebar .navigation {
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    background: #0077b4;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}

.main-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    transition: right 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: right 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: right 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: right 0.3s ease;
}

.main-nav.open {
    right: -300px;
}

.main-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-nav ul li {
    float: left;
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.main-nav ul li span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #fff;
}
```

My Question: The left blue element should move to the right side of the right "main-nav" gets moved.

Comment: And your question is...? Also you need to post your code *in* your question.

Comment: Please add your code to the question along with the fiddle. There is no guarantee that the fiddle link will stay alive

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the transition and the click effect to the navigation div, as well. Take a look at the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jqmtcon/2/)

**HTML**

```
<section class="sidebar">
    <div class="navwrap">
          <div class="navigation">
          </div><nav class="main-nav">
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Lorem</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Lorem</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Lorem</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Lorem</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><span>Lorem</span></a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
    </div>
      </section>
```

**CSS**

```
 .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}

.sidebar .navigation {
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    background: #0077b4;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.navwrap {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    transition: right 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: right 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: right 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: right 0.3s ease;
}

.main-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;

}

.open {
    right: -300px;
}

.main-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-nav ul li {
    float: left;
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.main-nav ul li span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #fff;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
 $( ".navwrap" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "open" );
});
```

Comment: This isn't a very nice solution :/ The blue element does not move very smooth at all.

Comment: you didn't specify smooth in the question, but i will look into it lol

Comment: @susanloek I have updated my answer. I added a wrap div around the entire nav, both divs included. They now transition together, smoothly :)